# Play 2.0.3 - Eclipse not recognizing play.test.WithApplication

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0

[image]

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/76JjbcE2dYw

I was looking at a similar question. I'm using Play 2.0.3 and it still doesn't work.

Any clue why ?

I'm following this tutorial - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is a work in progress, and is based on Play 2.1, which is not yet released.  You'll have to download and build Play 2.1 yourself if you want to use it.

Comment: :( Guess, I will just wait.